# Load large .obj file

Tags: ios, scenekit

I am working with the 3D model and I am using the Scene Kit for rendering and Model I/O for loading the obj file. It works perfectly fine for the small size of obj. But now I have 250MB of file and when It starts loading it takes too much memory and lower end devices are crashing.

How can I read this obj files that is used by the scene kit or any alternate way to read this file? Below is the line of code I used for reading obj file:

```
MDLAsset *asset = [[MDLAsset alloc]  initWithURL:mapURL];
MDLMesh *object = (MDLMesh*)[asset objectAtIndex:0];
```

Is there any alternative way to load large obj files?

Comment: use a different format that is much more compact and doesn't need post processing after reading.

Comment: .obj is a horrible, horrible, horrible format - yes, use something that's actually designed to be efficient.

Comment: You could write a converter that saves the .obj's parsed and processed data in a binary format that can be loaded quickly.

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but I am new in this field so can you please suggest which formate work best and gives the good performance?

Comment: .3ds is the de fraco industry standard format. It's binary and efficient.

.obj files are good because any programmer can write a parser just by looking at the ascii. However the point of writing such parser is to convert the obj file into a binary format which can be loaded faster.

Comment: And another question is why should a 250MB ascii file take up more than 250MB of memory?

Comment: Once it reads this file I am creating one array of selectable 300 objects so that is also increases the memory and may be I am doing wrong here

Answer (score 1):

Finally I resolved issue. Issue is with the Xcode I uninstalled everything and installed again and its stared working perfectly. And also there are some memory leaks in OpenGL so that I released.